# Add Checked in Checkbox if value same with value from database

Tags: php

i try to add checked in my checkbox if value in checkbox is same with value from database :

```
My database :
Column = skin_type 
Value = Normal, Dry, Oily

My Default html checkbox :
<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Normal">Normal &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Dry">Dry &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Oily">Oily &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Combination">Combination &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Sensitive">Sensitive
```

so if value is `Normal, Dry, Oily`  checkbox with this value will checked , example like below

[image]

Below is my current php script (*i try to explode the data first but not sure how to add checked if value is equal with value from database*) :

```
<?php 
$query_skin_type = mysql_query("SELECT skin_type FROM `customers` WHERE customers_id='".$_GET['cID']."'");
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query_skin_type)) {

$skin_type = explode(", ", $info['skin_type']);

    foreach ($skin_type as $value) {
    $value.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How you are storing this value in db table?

Comment: @LearneR  ->  if($_POST['skin_type'] == TRUE) { $skin_type_out = implode(', ', $_POST['skin_type']); }

Comment: Skin type is listing i mean Normal,Dry,Oily,Combination,Sensitive are static or dynamic?

Comment: static , i store all value in one column, if this below than 3 input i can seperate and create each value with different column(simple method) but i have more than 10 value for checkbox.

Comment: OP, give my answer a try. It should work for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write a little function to check against your $skin_type array. For example:

```
$skin_type = explode(", ", $info['skin_type']);

function isChecked($val, $arr){
  if(in_array($val, $arr)){
    echo 'checked';
  }
}

<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Normal" checked="<?php isChecked('Normal', $skin_type); ?>">Normal &nbsp;
//etc...
```

Please note that I would go about generating the markup in an entirely different way, but this will suffice without any refactoring.

Comment: not sure why , its checked all my checkbox. Btw i already write my solution using foreach inside input(this from your idea).

Comment: You need to change the first argument given to isChecked() to match the input value for each checkbox.

Comment: okay, i think we have 2 solution here but better use your code @Matthew it simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Normal" 
<?php
foreach ($skin_type as $value) {
if($value == "Normal") { echo "checked='checked'"; }
}
?> >Normal &nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Dry" <?php
foreach ($skin_type as $value) {
if($value == "Dry") { echo "checked='checked'"; }
}
?> >Dry &nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Oily"  
<?php
foreach ($skin_type as $value) {
if($value == "Oily") { echo "checked='checked'"; }
}
?> 
>Oily &nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Combination"  
<?php
foreach ($skin_type as $value) {
if($value == "Combination") { echo "checked='checked'"; }
}
?> 
>Combination &nbsp;

<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Sensitive"  <?php
foreach ($skin_type as $value) {
if($value == "Sensitive") { echo "checked='checked'"; }
}
?> 
>Sensitive
```

Comment: I won't downvote, but you don't need to loop at all for this and you've written way too much code for the task at hand...

Answer (score 0):

```
$skin_type = explode(", ", $info['skin_type']);


<input type="checkbox" name="skin_type[]" value="Normal" <?php if(in_array("Normal",$skin_type)){ ?>?checked="checked" <?php } ?>>Normal &nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0):

check box checked depend on data base value

`'<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="s_info[]" id="'.$ccid.'-S-'.$value['receipt_no'].'" value="'.$ccid.'-S-'.$value['receipt_no'].'" '. ($value['verified']? "checked":"") .'/>'.`